# Find an equation of a circle touching the origin that has curvature 4 at that point.

Tags: calculus

> Find an equation of a circle touching the origin that has curvature $4$ at that point.

Not sure how to parameterize the vector function with the translation. Also, radius is not given, so is this technically just open ended?

Comment: Circles have constant curvature, so you're looking for a circle passing through the origin with curvature 4. Do you know the relation between curvature and radius?

Comment: Yes, that derivation I have done. Also, the other commenter posted it, but yes. My hangup was on how to deal with the translation. I was putting the translation in the parametric equations then trying to derive that, and it became very hairy. I figured it was wrong, it shouldn't have been that complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the wording it seems that $$\kappa = \frac{1}{R} = 4$$ which means that the circle radius is $R=0.25$

The equation of the circle tangent to the $x$ axis, and passing through the origin, is $$ x^2 + (y-R)^2 = R^2$$

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much.